# Assigning local variable to by-reference parameter

Tags: c++, reference, scope

Coming from C, this example in Chapter 5 of Accelerated C++ caught my attention:

```
vector<Student_info> extract_fails(vector<Student_info>& students) {

    vector<Student_info> pass, fail;

    for (vector<Student_info>::size_type i = 0; i != students.size(); ++i)
        if (fgrade(students[i]))
            fail.push_back(students[i]);
        else
            pass.push_back(students[i]);

    students = pass;
    return fail;
}
```

Since `fail` is returned, I know it's not a problem for it to be a local variable. But why is `pass` able to make it out of the local scope?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably believe that the reference `students` is being "re-referenced" to the local variable `pass`. This is not the case. Instead, `operator=` is being called on the existing object passed in through `students`, and the data from `pass` is copied to it.

As you're coming from C, you're probably more familiar with pointers than with references. Let's assume that `students` was declared as a pointer, i.e.

```
vector<Student_info>* students
```

Your question implies that you believe the code you quoted is equivalent to the following

```
students = &pass;
```

when in fact it is equivalent to this

```
*students = pass;
```

The first of these two operations cannot, in fact, be carried out on a reference -- references cannot be "re-referenced".

Answer (score 3):

The `pass` object does not escape local scope.

The line `students = pass` copies the value of pass - for a vector, this is the elements - into students.

Answer (score 3):

`students` is passed by reference, thus allowing modification of the original value passed as parameter. The statement

```
students = pass;
```

does just that.